# Angularjs promises, notifying progress not updating bindings on time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to provide progress about a task running with angularjs but i'm having problem to updates the bindings when the deferred.notify() is executed.

Here is an example i made to reproduce the issue ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hIZZNgxhJLDqG02JYn5N?p=preview))

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
  'ngAnimate',
  'ui.bootstrap'
]);


(function() {
  'use strict';
  var controllerId = 'testController';
  angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['$timeout', '$q', '$scope', testController]);

  function testController($timeout, $q, $scope) {
    $scope.callLongProcess = callLongProcess;
    $scope.value = '-';
    $scope.progress = 0;


    function longProccess() {
      var def = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
          if (i % 2 === 0) {
            //WHY THIS LINES DOES NOT UPDATE THE UI WHEN RUNNING
            def.notify(i);
            $scope.$apply();
          }
        }
        def.resolve("success");
      }, 0);
      return def.promise;
    }


    function callLongProcess() {
      longProccess()
        .then(
          function(results) {
            $scope.value = results;
          },
          function(error) {
            $scope.value = error;
          },
          function(progress) {
            $scope.progress = progress;
          })
    }

  }
})();
```

Comment: These lines of code run synchronously and sequentially. You are updating the `$scope.progress` every time, but Angular has not yet had a chance to run a digest and update the View.

Comment: Here's how it would work: http://plnkr.co/edit/8LJihG78xD4pcuWkdM2h?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

You are stuck in a tight loop of 200000 iterations in your timeout function.  Even though you've called $scope.$apply 100000 times, the loop has to finish before the angular gets a chance to do anything.  That's because $scope.$apply runs asynchronously by adding another event to the main browser event loop, not running right away.

If you want to update progress you will have to break up the "longProcess" function into smaller chunks that you can process asynchronously with callbacks.